# Como añadir un valor a un vector en tiempo de ejecucion

Tags: java

Logro ingresar por consola la dimensión y los valores del *vector* ,  por ejemplo `|1|2|`  a ese vector quiero añadirle un valor cualquiera por consola puede ser el `6` y el resultado seria: `|1|2|6|` , pero no logro obtener ese resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
package arreglos;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner l = new Scanner(System.in);
        int op = 0;
        int n = 0;
        int v1[] = null;

        do {
            System.out.println("1. Ingresar  Vector");
            System.out.println("2. Mostrar Vector");
            System.out.println("3. Ingresar un elemento mas al Vector ");
            System.out.println("4. Comprobar tamaño del Vector");
            op = l.nextInt();

            switch (op) {

                case 1:

                    System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del vector:");
                    n = l.nextInt();

                    v1 = new int[n];

                    for (int i = 0; i < v1.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese dato en posicion:" + i);
                        v1[i] = l.nextInt();
                    }
                    System.out.println("" + '\n');

                    break;

                case 2:

                    System.out.println("");
                    for (int i = 0; i < v1.length; i++) {

                        System.out.print("|" + v1[i]);

                    }
                    System.out.println("" + '\n');

                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor a añiadir a el arreglo:");
                    n = l.nextInt();

                    System.out.println("Numero Ingresado:" + n);



                    System.out.println("" + '\n');

                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("" + '\n');
                    System.out.println("El tamaño del arreglo es:" + v1.length);
                    System.out.println("" + '\n');
                    break;

            }

        } while (op != 10);

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No es posible agregar un elemento más a un array. Los array tienen un tamaño fijo. Lo que debes hacer es utilizar una lista. Te recomiendo utilizar ArrayList, que como en tu caso querías un array, sería lo adecuado.

Se utiliza así:

```
ArrayList<Integer> v1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
v1.add(1);
v1.add(2);
v1.add(3);
```

Entonces, en tu caso, cuando entrás en el caso de agregar un elemento, simplemente haces `add`.

Comment: Federico siempre es mas recomendable usar la interface List en lugar ArrayList directamente ya que ayuda a mantener mayor flexibilidad como seria cuando tratas de cambiar a otro tipo de estructura.

Comment: Es verdad, no lo había pensado!

Answer (score 2):

En JAVA no puedes modificar el tamaño del arreglo el cual fue definido al declararlo, pero puedes hacer dos cosas :

1) Crear una copia del arreglo original el cual su largo debe ser largo original + nuevaCantidadDeValores :

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
    int [] arreglo = new int []{1,2,3,4,5};
    int nuevoValor = 6;
    System.out.println("largo del arreglo antes de modificar " + arreglo.length);
    arreglo = retornaNuevoArreglo(arreglo, nuevoValor);
    System.out.println("largo del arreglo despues de modificar " + arreglo.length);

    int [] arreglo2 = new int []{6,7,8,9,10};

    arreglo = retornaNuevoArreglo(arreglo, arreglo2);
    System.out.println(arreglo.length);
}

public static int [] retornaNuevoArreglo(int []arregloOriginal , int nuevoValor)
{
    int []nuevoArreglo = new int[arregloOriginal.length+1];
    for(int indice = 0;indice<arregloOriginal.length;indice++)
    {
        nuevoArreglo[indice] = arregloOriginal[indice];
    }
    nuevoArreglo[nuevoArreglo.length-1] = nuevoValor;
    return nuevoArreglo;
}

public static int [] retornaNuevoArreglo(int [] arreglo1,int []arreglo2)
{
    int [] arregloNuevo = new int [arreglo1.length + arreglo2.length];

    int indiceArregloNuevo = 0;
    for(int numero : arreglo1)
    {
        arregloNuevo[indiceArregloNuevo] = numero;
        indiceArregloNuevo++;
    }

    for(int numero : arreglo2)
    {
        arregloNuevo[indiceArregloNuevo] = numero;
        indiceArregloNuevo++;
    }

    return arregloNuevo;
}
```

2) Utilizar una lista (java.util.List) te dejo un codigo :

```
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add(5);
lista.add(10);
lista.add(3);
```

Comment: como hago las opcion numero 1?

Comment: He modificado la respuesta para satisfacer tu necesidad, espero te pueda servir , de caso contrario indicamelo y vuelvo a corregir :)